# Bootstrap column + vertical tabs in Safari is disturbed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, safari

To start, I don't (and happy about it) own anything from Apple.
But that faces me also with an problem, now it seems an new website is not correctly displayed when viewed with Apple's Safari browser. There are tools online to view an website in different browsers and OS but it is hard te find the problem then. So I am hoping someone here has any experience with this issue and knows how to solve this.

This image was send by one of my clients
[image]

But it should look like (https://torza.nl/portfolio_torza.php)
[image]

I think it is an `css` issue. This is the `tabs` `css`

```
.ui-tabs-vertical {
    width: 75em; 
}

.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav {
    padding: .2em .1em .2em .2em;
    float: left;
    width: 12.5em;
}

.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li {
    clear: left; width: 100%;
    border-bottom-width: 1px !important;
    border-right-width: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 -1px .2em 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li a {
    display:block; }

.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active {
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-right: .1em;
    border-right-width: 1px;
}

.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-panel {
    padding: 1em;
    float: right;
}

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav {
    background:#FFFFFF !important;
    border: none;
}

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav .ui-tabs-anchor {
  padding-left: 2px !important;
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

I have tried to remove `class` `d-flex` because that was the issue on another page of the same website. But that was not the solution.

Page

```
  <div class="col-lg-12 about-content">

    <div id="tabs" style="border: none;">

      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-2">
              <ul>

                <?php foreach($menu_array as $menu){ $i++; echo '<li><small><a href="#tabs-'.$i.'"><span style="display:inline-block; width:155px;">'.$menu[1].' '.$menu[2].'</span></a></small></li>'; } ?>

              </ul>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-10">

             <?php foreach($menu_array as $menu) { $j++; echo '<div id="tabs-'.$j.'">';

                $title = $menu[2];

                include('includes/header_portfolio_torza_web.php');

                if(file_exists('includes/portfolio_torza/page_'.$menu[0].'.php')) { include('includes/portfolio_torza/page_'.$menu[0].'.php'); }
                else { include('includes/portfolio_torza/page_00.php'); }

                include('includes/footer_portfolio_torza_web.php');

                echo '</div>';
             }
             ?>

         </div>

    </div>

  </div>
```

One of the included pages:

```
<div class="row">

    <?php
    if($title == '') { echo '<div class="col-lg-12 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center"><h1 class="text-center">'.$pdf_title.'</h1></div>'; }
    ?>

    <div class="col-lg-12 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">

        <p class="description" style="font-size: 14px;">
        Tegenwoordig versturen veel bedrijven online nieuwsbrieven naar hun klanten en werknemers. Deze nieuwsbrieven informeren lezers over updates binnen het bedrijf en leveren informatie die eraan verbonden is. Bovendien spelen nieuwsbrieven een rol in het opbouwen en in stand houden van de relaties met klanten<br >
        <br />
        In het Torza systeem is het mogelijk om elke aangemaakte contactpersoon direct toe te voegen aan een externe nieuwsbriefservice, zoals Mailchimp.
        </p>

    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it's been a while since I used Bootstrap, but assuming you have ability to edit the markup, change `<div class="col-lg-10">` to `<div class="col-lg-10" style="margin-right:-1px;">`

This solves it for me (using devtools).

Comment: Great! That works perfectly. Can you explain what exactly happens with this solution?

Comment: I believe the issue is with bootstrap code. It has the following code: .row:before { display: table, content: " " }. My guess is the content: " " creates additional width and pecause safari & chrome do pixel rounding slightly differently, and the 2 columns on the site add-up to 100%, with this extra space, safari pushes the 2nd column to the next line. In fact, perhaps a better solution would be to add width: 0; to that selector I have mentioned before.